# html - how to load another page in the middle of first page

Tags: html, css

i have embarrassing question concerning to  elementary knowledge of HTML

I would like Open/load  second page in my first page

Menu button which loads second page -

```
<li class="current"><a href="first.html" target = "myContent">About us</a></li>
```

part of my firstpage is called "myContent" but (Opening of second page) doesn´t work properly (Page is opened in another Window)

```
<div id="myContent" name="myContent" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:800;float:left;"> </div>
```

What amI doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: what are you expecting, and what is happening?

Comment: I have menu on the left side of page - Main Page,  About us, Contact us .... after click e.g.  About us   page loads Information about us (Idea  - Menu buttons remains, and middle part of page loads information about us, than main page and so ... )  Reality - page about us is loaded in  new Window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your `div#myContent` with an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe):

```
<iframe id="myContent" name="myContent" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:800;float:left;"> </iframe>
```

You may need to add some additional styling here.

Or you can use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) to load content with JS.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of the div

```
<iframe id='myContent'></iframe>
```